# What property should be used for reordering?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to be able to change the order using the arrows on the left and also delete specific items with the delete button on the right.

[image]

Now, I have the delete functionality in place but I'm a bit clueless on how to implement the reordering.

My entity looks like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string[] Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    public string Property 4{ get; set; }
}
```

My first idea was using an int property and order after it. I could swap two int properties when an arrow is pressed. If I deleted an element it would still work and if I added a new element I had to be sure to set it to max int+1. But it seems very clumsy and not efficient. Is there any better way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Order` column is the simpliest way you can do this.

for Adding:

```cs
//get max order
int maxOrder = context.Account.Max(r => r.Order);

var newRow = new Account{ Order = maxOrder + 1 //rest of the properties };
context.Account.Add(newRow);

//Update the rest of the rows
var rows = context.Account.Where(r => r.Order >= newRow.Order).ToList();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    row.Order++;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

For delete

```cs
var rowToDelete = context.Account.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == idToDelete);
context.Account.Remove(rowToDelete);

//Update the rest of the rows

var rows = context.Account.Where(r => r.Order > rowToDelete.Order).ToList();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    row.Order--;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

For reordering

```
//get rows between the current order and the new order that you want to assign

var rowsBetween = context.Account.Where(r => r.Order > Math.Min(rowToMove.Order, newOrder) 
                  && r.Order < Math.Max(rowToMove.Order, newOrder)).ToList();
```

`Math.Min(rowToMove.Order, newOrder)` and `Math.Max(rowToMove.Order, newOrder)` is important here because if you are moving the row up and down depending on the direction Min and Max function will work

Rest is just updated the Order in `rowsBetween`

```
foreach (var row in rowsBetween)
{
    if (rowToMove.Order < newOrder)
       row.Order--;
    else 
       row.Order++;

}
```